# Passing extras to the main activity from another one it calls

Tags: android, android-intent

In the **Main activity** I have a button to **add** a new Note (it's a sort of sticky notes android application):

```
ArrayAdapter<Note> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Note>) getListAdapter();
    Note note = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        // Call AddActivity to specify content of the note fields to be
        // added to the DB
        intentToAdd = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentToAdd);

        //get the extras from AddActivity
        Note newNote = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("myNewNote");

        String summary = newNote.getSummary();
        String details = newNote.getDetails();

        // Save the new note in the database
        note = datasource.createNote(summary, details);
        adapter.add(note);
        break;
```

Then I have the **AddActivity** (which contains a **form** to add a new Note), its **onCreate method** is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    butAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAjout);

    intentToMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    butAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText summary = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSum));
            EditText details = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDet));

            Note note =new Note(summary.toString(),details.toString());
            intentToMain.putExtra("myNewNote", note);

            startActivity(intentToMain);
        }
    });

}
```

**N.B : My Note Class implements Parcelable Class !**

Here's my problem:
**when I click on the add button in the main activity my application crashes ("stops unexpectedly") WHY :( ???**

Tell me if there is some other missing information or code... Thank you ...

The logCat says it's a nullPointerException:

```
04-21 17:00:07.832: D/AndroidRuntime(278): Shutting down VM
04-21 17:00:07.832: W/dalvikvm(278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.insat.notememoiresqlite.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 11 more
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 17:00:07.892: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 15 more
04-21 17:04:37.812: I/Process(278): Sending signal. PID: 278 SIG: 9
```

I think it's because of these lines in the Main Activity:

```
String summary = newNote.getSummary();
String details = newNote.getDetails();
```

where I try to get values from newNote while it's null
**But why is it null?**

**-----------------------------------------------------------Edit-----------------------------------------------------------**

**I've tried the onActivityResult solution, but i still have a NullPointerException for this line:**

```
Note newNote = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("myNewNote");
```

**Here is the code:
In Main Activity:**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Note>) getListAdapter();
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:
            // Call AddActivity to specify content of the note fields to be
            // added to the DB
            intentToAdd = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intentToAdd, 0);
            break;
```

**then:**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i("aaaaa", "Dans le onActivityResult ");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i("aaaaa", "RESULT_OK ");
            // get the extras from AddActivity
            Note newNote = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("myNewNote");
            if (newNote != null) {
                String summary = newNote.getSummary();
                String details = newNote.getDetails();

                // Save the new note in the database
                note = datasource.createNote(summary, details);
                adapter.add(note);

            } else {
                Log.i("aaaaa", "newNote est null !!!!!!!! ");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("aaaaa", "RESULT_PAS OK ");
        }
    }
```

**and in the AddActivity:**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        Log.i("aaaaa", "Dans le onCreate de AddActivity");

        butAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAjout);

        intentToMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        butAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("aaaaa", "Dans le onClick du bouton ajout");
                EditText summary = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSum));
                EditText details = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDet));

                Note note =new Note(summary.toString(),details.toString());
                intentToMain.putExtra("myNewNote", note);
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can get a fair idea of why a crash occurred by looking at Logcat.

Comment: you have it wrong. startActivity starts an activity, but it doesn't wait for it to start your main activity again. Use startActivityWithResult, and put your Note handling in the onActivityResult of your main Activity.

Comment: Is MainActivity your lanching activity?

Comment: @njzk2 I'll try that now

Comment: @njzk2 i've changed the code like you said but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Siho : you're implementation is fine, except instead of `getIntent()`, in `onActivityResult`, you have to use `data`, which is a parameter.

Comment: @njzk2 thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't work and the log cat shows `05-04 09:50:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(310): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 09:50:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at com.insat.notememoiresqlite.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:101)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this...

Make a static class which holds an instance of note,then in AddActivity add the values to it as

```
  StaticClass.noteitem.summary="abc";
  StaticClass.noteitem.details="abcdef";
```

then on the OnREsume of your mainactivity check

```
   if (StaticClass.noteitem!=null)
```

and access your item as StaticClass.noteitem.summary etc.