# Is there something wrong with my Parcelable class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

**I wonder if there is something wrong with my class because I can't pass extra (composed by a Note Object) from an activity to another**

Here is the code of my Parcelable Class: Note:

```
public class Note implements Parcelable {

    public static int compteur = 0;
    long id;
    String summary;
    String details;

    public Note(String summary, String details) {
        super();
        compteur = compteur + 1;
        this.id = compteur;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public Note() {
        super();
    }

    ///// getters and settters /////

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Note " + id + " (" + summary + ") --> Details: " + details;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeLong(id);
        dest.writeString(summary);
        dest.writeString(details);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Note> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Note>() {

        @Override
        public Note createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new Note(in);
        }

        public Note[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Note[size];
        }
    };

    private Note(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.summary = in.readString();
        this.details = in.readString();
    }
}
```

Or maybe the problem is anywhere else ??

Answer (score 0):

try making your Note constructor that accepts the Parcel public.

```
  public Note(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.summary = in.readString();
        this.details = in.readString();
    }
```

Comment: I've changed it to public but unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Comment: based on your question, do I gather correctly that you are trying to pass the Note Parcel from one activity to another?

Comment: what does your code look like for passing and reading that note parcel? it should look something like `Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class); i.putExtra("name.of.your.package.Note", noteObject);` and `Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); Note noteObject = b.getParcelable("name.of.your.package.Note");`

Comment: Here is the related topic to my problem [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133801/passing-extras-to-the-main-activity-from-another-one-it-calls

Comment: I'm exploring all possibilities

Comment: I'd like to mention that I'm using an SQLite database

Comment: Actually, it's the `Note noteObject = b.getParcelable("name.of.your.package.Note");` that is causing a nullPointerException.

Comment: Here is the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133801/passing-extras-to-the-main-activity-from-another-one-it-calls See the edited part